# Cannot authenticate user in MongoDB 3.0.2 using java connection

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication

1 - Created user in mongo shell

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.createUser( { user:"tiger", pwd:"secret", roles: [ { role:"readWrite", db:"zoo" } ] } )
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "tiger",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "zoo"
        }
    ]
}
```

2 - Connected to database from Java

```
List<ServerAddress> seeds = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
seeds.add( new ServerAddress( "remoteserver" ));
List<MongoCredential> credentials = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();  
credentials.add(
    MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential(
        "tiger",
        "admin",
        "secret".toCharArray()
    )
);
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( seeds);  //, credentials );
MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, "zoo");
```

3 - Insert a row

```
mongoTemplate.insert(animal, "animal");
```

4 - Get this error (this code works when I don't use authentication)

```
2015-05-13 23:11:36.166 ERROR 67846 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: { "serverUsed" : "remoteserver:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "auth failed" , "code" : 18}; nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "remoteserver:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "auth failed" , "code" : 18}] with root cause

com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "remoteserver:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "auth failed" , "code" : 18}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:76)
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort$NativeAuthenticator.authenticate(DBPort.java:652)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.authenticate(DBPort.java:364)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.checkAuth(DBPort.java:375)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.doOperation(DBTCPConnector.java:206)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.writeWithCommandProtocol(DBCollectionImpl.java:424)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insertWithCommandProtocol(DBCollectionImpl.java:389)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:188)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:167)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:93)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:78)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$8.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:904)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:410)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDBObject(MongoTemplate.java:899)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:721)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:676)
```

Answer (score 15):

A little digging and I found that Mongo 3 isn't fond of challenge-response and prefers '**MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential**'

```
List<ServerAddress> seeds = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
seeds.add( new ServerAddress( "remoteServer" ));
List<MongoCredential> credentials = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();
credentials.add(
    MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(
        "username",
        "adminDatabase",
        "password".toCharArray()
    )
);
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( seeds, credentials );
MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, "applicationDatabase");
mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory);
```

Comment: Please refer to this link for more details on authentication failures in mongo 3.0 due to change in auth mechanism - http://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/553/authentication-mongodb-3.x-failed-with-mechanism-mongodb-c#.VkCO-64rLGI

Comment: Switching to MongoCredential.createCredential worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

When using the maven dependency with artefactId "spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb" the **MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential** was not available.

So here is what I had to do:

A) Include the maven dependency to mongodb in the *pom.xml*:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

B) Using the solution from user4898172 (**MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential**)

```
public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
    List<MongoCredential> credentials = new ArrayList<>();
    credentials.add(MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(username, database, password.toCharArray()));

    return new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(host, port), credentials);
}
```

These two changes helped me solve the Exeption:

> com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" :
>   "remoteserver:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "auth failed" , "code"
>   : 18}

(I'm using MongoDB server version: 3.4.0)

The [mongodb github site](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/authenticating/) is also a good reference for implementation details.